# why imageData Will return nil in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift3, upload, nsdata

hi I want to convert images into Data but the problem is that the Data will return nil 
I want to upload images with Alamofire so I need to convert images before using Alamofire upload here is my codes

```
let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(ViewController.imageUpload[i], 1.0)


            Alamofire.upload(imageData! , to: "http://example.com/api/file?api_token=\(api_token)&id=\(postID)").responseJSON { response in
                debugPrint(response)
            }
```

Comment: Not sure what is ViewController here. print ViewController.imageUpload[i] and check you have images inside the array. If imageUpload is local variable, try using self.imageUpload.

Comment: these Are not local - I have count them and printed them

Comment: show me the print value of imageUpload and how you are adding images into imageUpload array?

Comment: <UIImage: 0x163a0ca0>, {40, 60}

Comment: how you are adding images into imageUpload array?

Comment: by append these images in another view controller

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152050/discussion-between-saeed-rahmatolahi-and-venkat).

Answer (score 2):

Try below code to get imageData and make sure you are passing right image there not nil,

For PNG:-

```
let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(ViewController.imageUpload[i]) as NSData?
```

For JPEG:-

```
let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(ViewController.imageUpload[i], 1.0) as NSData?
```

And also check which image extension you are using while saving (PNG or JPEG)

To know the image extension, please have a look into below code,

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
        if (!(picker.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.Camera)) {
            let assetPath = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as! NSURL
            if assetPath.absoluteString.hasSuffix("JPG") {
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: the problem is that these images has chosen by user in the gallery and I just copy them in this array so I don't know their names

Comment: how can I detect that image is png or JPG?

Comment: Check assetPath.absoluteString.hasSuffix in didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo function

Comment: can you tell me some way easier ? because I copied these images into static array as you see and the imagePickerController is in the another view controller please tell me the way that detect ViewController.imageUpload[i] is "JPG"  or  "PNG"

Comment: let's forgot to know about extension as of now. First check both the code and see you got imageData or not.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152046/discussion-between-neha-gupta-and-saeed-rahmatolahi).

Comment: Firstly, Check that the delegate method of image picker is call or not